# How do I remove the "launch" menu in Unity Launcher? I want folders to launch immediately

Tags: unity, 16.04, launcher, directory

Can I change the typical Unity layout in Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS (64-bit) so that I can launch folders just by clicking on their icons, instead of having to click on the icons, and then click "launch"? Because having to click the launch button every time is extremely unintuitive.

Also, what's the point of the back and forward buttons on the launcher? The only thing they accomplish for me is to cycle through the same folder endlessly. See this .webm: https://zippy.gfycat.com/MediocrePlaintiveIberianmole.webm

I use the Unity Launcher a lot, so I need it to immediately launch folders, especially the Downloads folders. I don't know why folder behaviour is different from program behaviour in Unity Launcher. The programs don't have a "launch" button, so why do the folders have them?

Any help at all is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Huh, I don't experience your back/forward button issue. I don't even have back/forward buttons.

Comment: If you hold the super/windows key you'll see a lot of useful shortcuts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Double click on the folders - they will launch / open immediately.

Comment: `Enter` also opens them immediately.

Comment: @AlcuinArundel that's also an alternative. Marking your comment as useful. Click + enter. Though that requires using both mouse and keyboard. Double-click is just mouse though

Comment: "Though that requires using both mouse and keyboard." Not necessarily. The Dash can be operated quite effectively from only the keyboard. Open it with `Meta`, type in your search keyword, arrow keys to navigate, `Enter` to open. However, the OP is using a mouse, so your point is well taken.

Comment: Hi, thank you for telling me how to do it the right way. Is there any way to make them launch with a single click?

Comment: @UnityLauncherProblems not to my knowledge, no. And I can expect that it  is not possible, unless you change source code of Unity itself.   Clicking events and how windows respond to them are typically hard - coded into them, and cannot be altered.